# Find all points outside of a quadrilateral (not a rectangle)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, bounding-box

## Question

I'm using PIL, and I have part of my code that requires finding which points are outside of a quadrilateral. If I have points like `[(50, 20), (230, 40), (200, 190), (100, 200)]`, how can I quickly fill all the points outside this area with black?

I want a function like `addBorder(points, img)`, where `addBorder([(50, 20), (230, 40), (200, 190), (100, 200)], Image.open('lenna.png'))` would return:

[image: output]

## What I've Found so Far

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935352/4414003) looked useful until I realized the link was dead. If anyone knows if the page linked in that answer still exists somewhere else, I'd love to see it. I tried a few algorithms before I realized that they only worked for rectangles.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any point is either going to be between two line segments, or outside. Knowing that you should be able to figure it out. It's not a hard problem.

Comment: The page linked in that answer is [archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130125232758/http://wiki.processing.org/w/Find_which_side_of_a_line_a_point_is_on).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way that doesn't involve checking every pixel, but I found my answer in rules for filling. I used the [even-odd rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule).